# Facebook TAB (iFrame): Use Facebook's JavaScript absoluteTop to keep a div at the top of te page all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, facebook-canvas, iframe-app

I work at a radiostation so I made a playlist of the played tracks from this radiostation, you can find it here -> http://www.facebook.com/QmusicNL?sk=app_258630990850514

The titlebar of the playlist should get a fixed position when scrolling down. It works when viewing the page on it's own server. But Facebook disabled a few functionality's in the iFrame so you can't screw up anything above the iFrame. Now I found that Facebook does provide that option trough an alternate way. (absoluteTop) But I cant get it to work properly.

**In short:**
Can anyone provide a good snippet of JavaScript that keeps a DIV always on top of the browser inside an iFrame within a Facebook tab on a "page" of Facebook? Or else an example would be nice too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to position a div at the top of the iframe? To do this you don't need javascript; applying the css: 'position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;' will keep the div at the top of the page, even when scrolling.

Comment: Usually this would work, but since it is positioned within an iFrame it doesn't. Thnx anyway!